# Doubt in terminal

Tags: bash

I'am new to linux and ubuntu. I have installed and removed budgie desktop
after that when I open terminal I'am seeing "bash: /etc/profile.d/vte.sh: No such file or directory" in terminal .please help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unistaller must have removed that file, don't worry. Simply create it at the same path and paste this as content.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8D2JKfTrW9/

Answer (score 5):

Just look in your /etc/profile.d folder: `ls -l /etc/profile.d/vte*` to see if there are any files starting with vte. In my case I found two files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1368 Jun 11  2020 /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  966 Jun 11  2020 /etc/profile.d/vte.csh
```

If you find the above, then you can just create a link to one of the files:

```
cd /etc/profile.d
sudo ln -s vte-2.91.sh ./vte.sh
```

And the problem goes away.

You can use the solution provided by Mattia, if no `vte*` files are found in `/etc/profile.d`